# get the path of an uploaded file in drupal 7

Tags: forms, file, path, get, drupal-7

I am now working with drupal 7 and this a form to upload a photo from desktop:

```
     $form['Background image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file', 
    '#title' => t('Image'), 
    '#page arguments' => array('testform'),
    '#access callback' => TRUE,
    '#description' => t('Click "Browse..." to select an image to upload.'),
    //Get the file path

    );
```

my question is how to get the path  of the selected photo so I can later create an object (using the photo´s path ) to be saved in the database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your submit handler you will have access to the submitted file properties.

you can do like this to get the file url:

Load the files object with this:

```
$files_obj = file_load($form_state['values']['Background image']);
```

Get the url:

```
$url = file_create_url($files_obj->uri);
```